# Can you use the framework version to control what to compile (in C#)?

Tags: c#, c-preprocessor

I need to exclude some code from the compilation when targeting the .NET 3.5 framework, but not when targeting 2.0. Is this possible using preprocessor conditions (#if/#endif)? Or maybe some other method.

**Oops, duplicate.. closing...**

Comment: Hmm.. do I have to vote to close my own question.. strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look Here: [Conditional compilation depending on the framework version in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408908/conditional-compilation-depending-on-the-framework-version-in-c)