# Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported. (ASP.NET MVC and Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am stuck in somewhere on my ASP.NET MVC 3 app. here is the error I am getting :

> The specified type member 'AccommPropertyTags' is not supported in
>   LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity
>   navigation properties are supported.

I have found how we can solve this on following article :

[Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919709/only-initializers-entity-members-and-entity-navigation-properties-are-supported)

But mine is a little bit odd.

Here is one of the partial class of my entity :

```
[MetadataType(typeof(AccommPropertyWebDetail.MetaData))]
public partial class AccommPropertyWebDetail {

    public virtual ICollection<string> AccommPropertyTags {

        get {

            return Helpers.AccommPropertyTag.CreateStringListFromString(this.PropertyTags);
        }
    }

    private class MetaData {

        [Required, StringLength(50)]
        public string Category { get; set; }

    }
}
```

As you can see above, `AccommPropertyTags` property is typeof `ICollection<string>`. What I am trying inside my controller is as follows :

```
public ViewResult Tag(string tag) {

    var _rawTag = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(tag);

    ViewBag.Tag = _rawTag;

    var model = _accommpropertyrepo.GetAllAccommPropertiesFullWebIgnoringApprovalStatus();

    model = model.Where(
            x => x.AccommPropertyTags.Any(
                    y => y == _rawTag
                )
        );

    return View(model);
}
```

Because of the fact that I am using `Any` there, Entity is trying to convert my `AccommPropertyTags` property to SQL and cant because it's not part of the table schema.

Am I really stuck here or is there a cool way of beating this annoying error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is similar to the question you have linked. Call `model.ToList()` before using `Where`. This will force EF to materialize entities and then apply the rest of the filtering in memory.

```
public ViewResult Tag(string tag) {

    var _rawTag = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(tag);

    ViewBag.Tag = _rawTag;

    var model = _accommpropertyrepo.GetAllAccommPropertiesFullWebIgnoringApprovalStatus();

    var result = model.ToList().Where(
            x => x.AccommPropertyTags.Any(
                    y => y == _rawTag
                )
        );

    return View(result);
}
```