# A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType does not declare a navigation property with the name *

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to get data from a LocalDb into my MVC Controller. I tried this:

```
UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
var users = db.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
                           .Include(u => u.LastName).ToList();
```

It returns this error:

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType
>   'ChatProj.Models.UserProfile' does not declare a navigation property
>   with the name 'LastName'.

[Here is a picture of my localDb and model.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjXzI.jpg)

Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: I would rather suggest you go through this post
<b>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356541/entity-framework-linq-query-include-multiple-children-entities</b>

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Navigation property should be of entity type of collection of related entities. Including some navigation property means *joining* your current entity with some related entity or entities. That allows eager loading of data from several tables in single query. `LastName` is not a navigation property - it is simple field, and it will be loaded by default, you don't need to include it:

```
UsersContext db = new UsersContext();
var users = db.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
                           .ToList();
```

This query will be translated into something like

```
SELECT UserId, UserName, LastName, FirstName 
FROM UserProfiles
WHERE UserId = @value
```

Comment: Cheers m8, great answer!

Comment: @JazzMaster welcome :) consider also reading about [Navigation Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, would you mind taking a look at my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988951/export-to-excel-linq-include-foreignkey-values-in-tolist

Comment: so there is no way to avoid always loading all properties in UserProfiles?

Comment: The most common mistake I see people, including myself, make, is Including an enum property.  Or, refactoring an entity to just be an enum, and then this silently blows up in your face.

Answer (score 26):

`Include` is only for navigation properties, and `LastName` is a scalar property, so you don't need `Include` at all.

Comment: Couldn't've said it better, myself.  Very succinct.

Comment: I didn't know where an error I had came from, untill I saw your answer. Said enough. +1

Answer (score 22):

Even though this is not quite related to the question, since Google brings you here, I thought it might be helpful to notice that a likely possibility is that you are using `IEnumerable` for your collection. Instead you should be using `ICollection`, see more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32997694/550975

This seems to be a problem in `EF6` and perhaps earlier versions only... no longer a problem to use either in `EF Core`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to retrieve only the `LastName`, use

```
Select(m => m.LastName)
```

so

```
 var users = db.UserProfiles
                .Where(u => u.UserId == WebSecurity.CurrentUserId)
                .Select(u => u.LastName)//not Include
                .ToList();
```

`LastName` is just a string (Scalar property) in your model, not a Navigation property (relation with another entity)

Answer (score -2):

In my case I solved it as the following

the code with the error :

```
LabResults = db.LAB_RESULTS.Where(o => o.ORDER_ID == id)
.Include(p => p.LabTests).ToList()
```

then I removed .Include :

```
LabResults = db.LAB_RESULTS.Where(o => o.ORDER_ID == id).ToList()
```

Comment: This solution is not directly relevant to question and doesn't solve it either. :)