# Expression-bodied function members efficiency and performance in C# 6.0

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

In a new C# 6.0 we can define methods and properties using lambda expressions.

For instance this property

```
public string Name { get { return First + " " + Last; } }
```

can be now defined as follows:

```
public string Name => First + " " + Last;
```

The information about expression-boided function members you can find here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/11/20/new-features-in-c-6.aspx

Does anyone know if there's any overhead when using new syntax? Can it slow down (or improve efficiency of) the application or maybe it doesn't matter?

Comment: It is just syntax sugar, it doesn't affect the generated code at all.  Use ildasm.exe to convince yourself.

Comment: I don't know this feature, but i'm fairly sure that every syntactic sugar is just compiled to the same code. So there is no difference in runtime performance.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

> In a new C# 6.0 we can define methods and properties using lambda expressions.

No, you can't. You can define method and property bodies using syntax which *looks* like a lambda expression, in that it uses the token `=>`.

However, importantly this does *not* mean that there's a delegate type involved. (Whereas a lambda expression is only permitted in a context where it's converted to an expression tree or delegate type.)

This is purely syntactic sugar. Your two example code snippets will compile to the exact same IL. It's *just* a different way of representing the body of a property getter or method.

Comment: @JonSkeet This still true years / versions / enhancements later?... granted compilers are smart for inlining and such... but wouldn't there potentially be better odds / a different / more efficient way to transition from the caller to the expression evaluation?... I say this admittedly knowing almost 0 of IL or rosalyn, maybe just hopeful :) ... thanks!

Comment: @ScottBrickey: I'm not sure what you're expecting - a method (or whatever) is still just a method. If you're thinking of things like inlining, that's an optimization the JIT compiler can make. But adding a delegate type in there definitely wouldn't make it more efficient.

Answer (score 10):

They will compile down to the same IL,  you can always test this yourself by doing it and using ildasm to extract the IL.