# What is the benefit of using "Expression Bodied Functions and Properties"

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I do have seen many using that *new feature*, but what is the benefit of using those expressions?

### [Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx):

```cs
public override string ToString() => string.Format("{0}, {1}", First, Second);

public string Text =>
string.Format("{0}: {1} - {2} ({3})", TimeStamp, Process, Config, User);
```

This question is different to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411335/expression-bodied-function-members-efficiency-and-performance-in-c-sharp-6-0), because I am not only asking if the performance and efficiency does change, but also about the difference of the compiled code (IL code) and if it is best practice and should be used in the real world.

This question is also **not** [off topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), because I am asking for real life enterprise experience and not recommendations. Therefore don't recommend, but explain why you would or why you would not use that feature and what experiences you have with it!

Comment: Brevity. Writing the same thing, but shorter. It allows the developer to omit the braces and the return statement.

Comment: Readabilty? Compactness? What are the benefits of auto-properties?

Comment: Interesting approche. Does it also provide performance enhancements?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411335/expression-bodied-function-members-efficiency-and-performance-in-c-sharp-6-0

Comment: @Ofiris I do have read that question, but does somebody really know, if it is exactly the same? Like is the compiled code the same length and the same content? Or are there some changes? Some real world examples?

Comment: @TheRealVira Some of the answeres there shows that the compiled IL code is the same for the same content.

You can test it yourself using LinqPad.

Comment: @Ofiris I would like to see some examples and how the interpreter would handle such expressions.

Comment: @TheRealVira It's basically up to the compiler implementation but as I said, go ahead and view some IL generated code.

Comment: [Just test it and view by yourself](http://tryroslyn.azurewebsites.net/#f:>ilr/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28BQBvJ0PQA4FcBGIAlsNBAC4BOhAdgObQAqApgB5kCM0AvAHzQBEAM0T8A3Oky4CxUpRr1mbAEzQU0WkzKroFTTgrUBw+GOgBfc0jNA===)

Comment: @ All -> I do want to have an enterprise like view on that question, if it is good or bad practice and if it is used in enterprise code. I do have answered the question from my [point of view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321431/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-expression-bodied-functions-and-properties/40321985#40321985).

Comment: For the differences, regarding performance and generated IL, see the linked question: It’s the same. As for whether it’s good practice, or what the benefit of using it is; it is a subjective opinion (thus off topic for SO). Use it, if you like it, don’t use it, if you don’t like it. It’s shorter, so that’s already enough for many people. But I would personally avoid using it, where the involved expressions gets longer or more complicated.

Comment: @Ofiris *“It's basically up to the compiler implementation”* – It’s not up to the implementation. The equivalence of expression bodied functions and properties to their normal code is guaranteed by the language specification. Compilers are required to produce the same IL for them.

Comment: @poke, thanks for the comment, please note that MS compiler will generate different IL code when not specifing `/optimize`

Comment: IMHO:
(1) This is a pure marketing feature! at the end of the day, C# and Visual Studio is a product, so somewhere in the management level someone decides which feature to include in the language, from the perspective of that person this might be a useful feature, from the perspective of some developers it might not.
(2) Programming is not always an objective science like physics or math, the rules of physics and math apply everywhere, so no two mathematicians argue like this:

Answer (score 10):

It provides better readability and saves some space in your code. It is just nicer.

Comment: This is an short and good answer about what is good on using those expressions. Plus 1 for that!

Comment: Even though it makes methods more concise, I've found the extended method declarations to be easier to follow by eye since they preserve the indenting consistently across the class members.

Comment: Brevity is a nice thing, but more important to me is the fact that the `=>` indicates a functional Result that very likely has no side-effects. This makes me much more confident in Code-Reviews, provided the functions used (recursively) don't have side effects either.

Comment: @Spoc but this is not true, e.g.: `void Func() => _hdd.Format();` Why you say "very likely no side effects"? It's just a normal function with sugarcoated syntax, no any additional constraints applied.

Comment: @Zoli you are right, of course. I would not apply `=>` for Methods (that return nothing/void), 
only for Functions.

The fact that `=>` allows only a single Expression, 
together with the Fact that the Function returns a Value 
requires that all Functions used in this Expression also return a Value.

And with some discipline by every developer in a project, 
these Functions are written side-effect-free. 
And that allows me to deduce with some confidence 
that the whole Expression is also free of side-effects,
which makes code-reviews much easier.

Comment: @Zoli enabling [the detection of unused Function Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0058) further encourages writing Functions without Side-Effects, because any usage only for their side-effect would be flagged. 

This even applies to fluent APIs, which are designed to return the next Step, but only if they eventually return their Construct, instead of having Side-Effects like e.g. Console.Write.

Answer (score 9):

Answering one of my questions. I have tested out, if the IL code is the same with the following results:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(MyClass.GetTexted);
}

class MyClass
{
    private static string dontTouchMe = "test";

    public static string GetTexted { get { return dontTouchMe + "1"; } }

    //public static string GetTexted => dontTouchMe + "1";
}
```

... will generate the **same** IL code:

```
00993376  call        [random value]
0099337B  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax  
0099337E  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
00993381  call        71886640  
00993386  nop  
        }
00993387  nop  
00993388  lea         esp,[ebp-0Ch]  
0099338B  pop         ebx  
0099338C  pop         esi  
0099338D  pop         edi  
0099338E  pop         ebp  
0099338F  ret
```

The `[random value]` part is the only code that has changed, which does make sense since it changes every time it is getting compiled.

---

I am still a student at school, so I can only answer the other questions from my perspective (which is not an enterprise view):

- ”Expression Bodied Functions and Properties” do seem like a good practice due to a more compact and readable code. (thx to [@Wazner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5082427/wazner) and [@MacakM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7026647/macakm))
- It does also make sense to use them, because they look more modular and more like OOP code

Answer (score 8):

A body expression provides only a compact and cleaner way to declare a readonly property.
From a performance point of view, you write this:

```
public bool MyProperty {
    get {
        return myMethod();
    }
}

private bool myMethod() {return true;}
```

or this:

```
public bool MyProperty => myMethod();
private bool myMethod() {return true;}
```

There is no difference because it's translated into `IL` in the same way.
But pay attention to this thing: the body expression is a feature available by default on Visual Studio 2015 and newer version but if you want use in older VS version you need to install C# 6.0 from NuGet.

Comment: Other Visual Studio IDEs do also support c# 6.0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28638547/c-sharp-6-0-support-in-visual-studio-2012

Comment: You can use Expression-body in method declaration too
    `public bool MyProperty => myMethod();
    private bool myMethod() => true;`