# what is this feature called in c# and which version of c# uses this

Tags: c#

I am using this line of code in my project and haven`t seen this syntax.

```
 internal static StringBuilder a(this StringBuilder sb, string b) => sb.Append(b).Append("\n");
```

can anyone tell me what is this called so that I can study more about this.

Comment: I'm going to assume they mean the expression bodied method syntax.

Comment: It is called [Expression Bodied Member and Properties.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40321431/what-is-the-benefit-of-using-expression-bodied-functions-and-properties)

Comment: which ever you know. I can read about all. specially function with =>

Comment: `this StringBuilder sb`: [Extension Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the lambda arrow `=>`, it is a feature of C# 6 (expression-bodied function members). Check https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#expression-bodied-function-members

Comment: this is what i was looking for Expression bodied function members

Answer (score 1):

`internal static StringBuilder a(this StringBuilder sb, string b)`

This part tells us that `a` is an **extension method** to `StringBuilder`. You can read more on extension methods [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods)

`=> sb.Append(b).Append("\n")`

These are functions with no statement body. Instead, you implement them with an expression following the function declaration. This is new feature in C# 6. and called **expression-bodied function members.** You can read more about them [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/12/17/c-6-feature-review-expression-bodied-function-members/)

Answer (score 0):

This line consists of two main features. The first is an extension method which is the method signature defined to the left of the lambda symbol (`=>`) and can be identified as an extension method as it uses the `this` keyword before the first parameter. The second is called an expression bodied function which is the part to the right of the lambda symbol.

[Extension methods](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/csharp-3.0/extension-methods/)

[Expression bodied functions](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2015/12/17/c-6-feature-review-expression-bodied-function-members/)