# ; expected line 9 column 45

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am developing an app from a pre-written project. While building the solution I get this error:

> **;expected**  on line 9 column 45

The VS IDE gives a red underline to the "=>" on line 9.

I am using Visual Studio 2008. I don't understand where the fault is.

Here is my code:

```cs
    using System;
    using System.Net;
    using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

    namespace Main.Tools
    {
        internal static class Blockr
        {
            private static string BlockrAddress => "http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/";
            internal static double GetPrice()
            {
                var request = BlockrAddress + "coin/info/";
            var client = new WebClient();
            var result = client.DownloadString(request);

            var json = JObject.Parse(result);
            var status = json["status"];
            if ((status != null && status.ToString() == "error"))
            {
                throw new Exception(json.ToString());
            }

            return json["data"]["markets"]["coinbase"].Value<double>("value");
        }

        internal static double GetBalanceBtc(string address)
        {
            var request = BlockrAddress + "address/balance/" + address;
            var client = new WebClient();
            var result = client.DownloadString(request);

            var json = JObject.Parse(result);
            var status = json["status"];
            if ((status != null && status.ToString() == "error"))
            {
                throw new Exception(json.ToString());
            }

            return json["data"].Value<double>("balance");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Delete the `>` after the equal sign on line 9.

Comment: @ClaudioP While it'd compile, it's now turned it into a mutable field, rather than an immutable property as it used to be

Comment: @Rob A `readonly` keyword would be the same. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @ClaudioP It'd be closer, but it'd still break if one were to use reflection, and expected a property rather than a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put `private static string BlockrAddress = "http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/";` instead of `private static string BlockrAddress => "http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/";`

Comment: @PraveenYadav fyi, this changes the meaning of the original code from a read only property, to a mutable field

Comment: yeah, this should indeed be considered, as it changes the previous behavior

Answer (score 5):

On line 9 you have

```
private static string BlockrAddress => "http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/";
```

This type of property defination is a c# 6 feature and unsupported in vs 2008. Change it to

```
private static string BlockrAddress {
    get { return "http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/"; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

this is C#6 Syntax ([expression bodied member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28411335/expression-bodied-function-members-efficiency-and-performance-in-c-sharp-6-0)), only available since Visual Studio 2015:

```
private static string BlockrAddress => "http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/";
```

change this to:

```
private static string BlockrAddress get { return "http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/" }; //property
```

or

```
private static readonly string BlockrAddress = "http://btc.blockr.io/api/v1/"; //field
```

and it should solve the issue