# Computed property with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper to map my Entity to my DTO. I have a property which compares two lists in my entity and return true or false if equal.

```
public bool AreAllEmployeesInformed
    {
        get
        {
            var result = (from a in Employees
                join b in EmployeesInformed on a.Id equals b.Id
                select a).Count();

            if ((result == Employees.Count) && (result == EmployeesInformed.Count))
                return true;
            return false;

        }
    }
```

This is my mapping config

```
MappingConfiguration.CreateMap<Entities.Action, ForeManListItemDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Informed, x => x.MapFrom(y=>y.Activity.AreAllEmployeesInformed))
```

I want to map this to my DTO as true or false, but AutoMapper refuses. How can I fix this?

The error it gives me is "The specified type member 'Activity' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show the relevant CreateMap code, and how it fails?

Comment: This looks like [an EF problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919709/only-initializers-entity-members-and-entity-navigation-properties-are-supporte) rather than an AutoMapper one.

Comment: Are you calling Mapper.Map or ProjectTo? And I shudder to think what the SQL that little snippet is generating if it's using EF lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the both property to Informed and it will be mapped probably.
If you don't would like to, I tried it as a method and it works for me
For instance:
change:

```
public bool AreAllEmployeesInformed
    {
        get
        {
            var result = (from a in Employees
                join b in EmployeesInformed on a.Id equals b.Id
                select a).Count();

            if ((result == Employees.Count) && (result == EmployeesInformed.Count))
                return true;
            return false;

        }
    }
```

to :

```
public bool AreAllEmployeesInformed()
    {
        get
        {
            var result = (from a in Employees
                join b in EmployeesInformed on a.Id equals b.Id
                select a).Count();

            if ((result == Employees.Count) && (result == EmployeesInformed.Count))
                return true;
            return false;

        }
    }
```