# Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<IEnumerable> to <IEnumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have two classes Employee and Territory:

```
public class Territory
{        
    public string TerritoryID { get; set; }
    public string TerritoryDescription { get; set; }       
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to pull Employees by TerritoryID using LINQ and getting exception:

```
IEnumerable<Employee> empList = context.Territories
  .Where(x => x.TerritoryID == territoryID)
  .Select(y => y.Employees)
  .ToList();
```

Exception is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Employee>> to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Employee>. An explicit
>   conversion exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `SelectMany()` method instead of `Select()`

What you are doing here with `Select()` is creating a new Enumerable containing all the Employees Collections.

`SelectMany` flattens all the 'child' collections and aggregate every employee into a single Enumerable.

---

For the second problem, described in the comments, it seems that `Employees` is not known in the Table Schema or as a Navigation Property.

One fix would be to call `ToList()` before the `SelectMany()` call to ensure the SQL query is executed and the remaining operations are executed in-memory.

This is based on this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919709/only-initializers-entity-members-and-entity-navigation-properties-are-supporte)

Comment: Great! compile error gone by using SelectMany(), Now at run time I am getting "The specified type member 'Employees' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported."

Comment: Do you have a DBSet of Employees in your Context class?

Comment: If not you might need to add an `.Include(t => t.Employees)` before the `SelectMany`.

Comment: @Gaurav  If your goal is to just get an IEnumerable instead of a List collection just change the extension to 'ToArray()' instead. EG(Something similar in my code) IEnumerable<teOrder> orders = context.tePersons.SelectMany(x => x.teOrders).ToArray();

Comment: @Botonomous, yes i have DBSet of Employees in Context class.

Comment: @Gaurav It seems that there is another question that seems pretty close to your second problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6919709/only-initializers-entity-members-and-entity-navigation-properties-are-supporte

Comment: @Sidewinder94, unable to add .Include before SelectMany() : trying like - IEnumerable<Employee> empLst = context.Territories.Where(x => x.TerritoryID == Territories).Include(t => t.Employees).SelectMany(y => y.Employees).ToArray();