# How to detect on compile time if the target .NET runtime is 4.0 or above?

Tags: c, visual-studio, msbuild

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436526/detect-target-framework-version-at-compile-time) but now that we also have 4.5 the solution won't work.
How can I check if the runtime is above 4.0?
Since it's a string I am guessing I cannot do:

```
<DefineConstants Condition=" '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' >= 'v4.0' ">NET_4_0</DefineConstants>
```

So should I define both:

```
<DefineConstants Condition=" '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.0' ">NET_4_0</DefineConstants>
<DefineConstants Condition=" '$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.5' ">NET_4_5</DefineConstants>
```

Is there a more generic solution?

Comment: The `>` and `<` operators only work on strings that contain numbers, the "v" screws that up.  I see nothing wrong with your workaround, albeit that you probably just want to treat 4.5 as 4.0, allowing OR.  You could also use `<Choose> + `<When>`

Comment: Could you please show me an alternative solution. I never dealt with those things before.

Comment: @HansPassant sorry, forgot to mention your nick.

Comment: Use the MSDN Library for examples:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164282.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize any methods from the System.String class in the .NET Library, including comparisons.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633440.aspx

**Edit**

And if you can't get property functions to work well enough for you, you could try the MSBuild Extension Pack.  http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/help/3.5.3.0/html/9c5401ed-6f55-089e-3918-2476c186ca66.htm

Comment: So you'd write `<DefineConstants Condition="$([System.String]::Compare($(TargetFrameworkVersion), 1, "v4.0", 1, 3, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreCase))">NET_4_0</DefineConstants>`? Will it work?

Comment: @the_drow Not sure.  Haven't tried Compare yet.  I know that the Contain method works on a string instance though. `<DefineConstants Condition="$(TargetFrameworkVersion.Contains('v4.'))">NET_4_0</DefineConstants>`.  Not sure if this is what you want or not though.  I've found the guidance on where exactly to place $ to be a bit obtuse.

Comment: It will work until 5.0 arrives. I need numerical comparsion of the version number.

Comment: @the_drow If you can get the usage of `$` right in your bit above, I feel pretty confident this will work.  You might want to ignore the culture and casing issues though, as you have a pretty good idea of the culture and format already.  Try the simple signature instead.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84787k22.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Carrying on from @MichaelPrice's answer & @HansPassant's comment...

```
<Choose>
  <When Condition=" '$(TargetFrameworkVersion.Substring(1,3))'&gt;'3.5' ">
    <ItemGroup>
      <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);NEWERTHANNET35</DefineConstants>
    </ItemGroup>
  </When>
</Choose>
```