# Code Contracts: how to suppress this "requires unproven" warning?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, code-contracts

I have a piece of code for which `cccheck` tells me that a `Requires()` is unproven and that I should add a `!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(...)`. That condition is already checked for as I call my own extension method that I have written back in the days of .Net 3.5:

```
public static bool IsEmpty(this string s)
{
    if (s == null) return true;
    if (s.Length == 0) return true;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        if (!char.IsWhitespace(s[i]))
            return false;
    return true;
}

public static bool IsNotEmpty(this string s)
{
    return !IsEmpty(s);
}
```

My code already requires that `value` is `IsNotEmpty`:

```
Contract.Requires(value.IsNotEmpty(), "The parameter 'value' cannot be null or empty.");
```

How can I tell `cccheck` (and the rest of the Code Contracts framework) that `IsNotEmpty()` already checks for `!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(...)`?

Comment: Disregarding the issues I see with your implementation, I'm curious why you implemented your own version of IsNullOrWhitespace(). Perhaps this would be a good time to reconsider your approach...?

Comment: Simply because it takes less keystrokes to write `value.IsEmpty()` than `string.IsNullOrWhitespace(value)`. I wrote the `IsEmpty()` extension method before `IsNullOrWhitespace` was added to `string`. `IsNullOrEmpty` wasn't enough in an earlier project. I kept the method as part of a `StringHelpers` static class full of extension methods. I still use that class in newer projects since my webhost doesn't support .Net 4. @RickLiddle What issues are you refering to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result() == !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s))`

EDIT:

Yes, I realized this would cause "ensures unproven" when I posted it and I was hoping to find some time to answer more thoroughly.  One (somewhat trivial) way to fix it, if you can stand throwing away your old code:

```
public static bool IsEmpty(this string s) 
{ 
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result() == string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s))
    return string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s);
} 

public static bool IsNotEmpty(this string s) 
{ 
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result() == !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s))
    return !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(s);
}
```

Comment: This results in a “ensures unproven” instead of the previous “requires unproven”. :( Yet, on the right path, I think.

Comment: A viable solution! And if I combine it with the solution given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436526, I can keep my old code if I reference StringHelpers.csproj in another project written for .Net 3/3.5.