# how to have only one project for different versions of .NET?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Well, I have a project, and by the moment I am using .NET 4.0, because I would like that this application is compatible with windows XP, because EF 5.0 is only for windows 7 and upper.

However, I would like to implement some parts of the application with the features of .NET 4.5, such as EF 5.0.

So for my database access I have a reposotry class that now use EF 4.0, this is a independent dll, so I can create other repository dll that use EF 5, and in my project import both dlls, then I can instantiate the correct repository according to the version of EF 5.0 that I can use. This is a paramater in the config file. is this the best way?

I ask this because I don't know where I must declare my interface. because my repository classes need to implement this interface, but then this tie my dlls to my application, but I need to use this repositories in two different applications, so I want to implement once, and use in many applications. I want independent dlls, because now are two applications, but in the future, can be more.

The reason to want to use an interface in the application that uses the repositories is because I would like to instantiate at runtime the correct repository, according to the config file settings. So in the fututre I can implement new repositories and there is no needed to change the code.

EDIT1: I read about multi targeting, but if in my project I use features for example of .NET 4.0 and I want to complie for 3.5, I get an error because this feature does not exist in 3.5. That's correct. Then the only way is to mantain two different projects? It would be a double work.

Thanks.
Daimroc.

Comment: Just a couple of comments. EF5 is available for both .NET 4 and .NET 4.5, although some of the new features are only available when using .NET 4.5. EF6, for which alpha1 is currently available from NuGet, supports all features except async on .NET 4 and .NET 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So for my database access I have a reposotry class that now use EF
>   4.0, this is a independent dll, so I can create other repository dll that use EF 5, and in my project import both dlls, then I can
>   instantiate the correct repository according to the version of EF 5.0
>   that I can use. This is a paramater in the config file. is this the
>   best way?

You can go this route and I don't really see an issue with it unless you think that this could cause maintenance/development headaches in the future. There are a couple of other things that you can look into doing. I think both are completely valid and probably just personal opinion/preference.

1. **Modules** You can go a modular route where your repository DLLs are potentially loaded dynamically. Look into [Microsoft's Unity library](http://unity.codeplex.com/). This should allow you to create an IModule in each of your repository DLLs that will set up your application as needed. Then just create a UnityBootstrapper class to tell it how to find your modules (manually add them, look in a directory, etc.). This should allow you to hot swap your repository DLLs and not have to worry about setting a config file if you don't want to.
2. **Preprocessor Directives** With preprocessor directives you get to define how your code will compile. Depending on how you have your classes structured this may be something fairly simple to set up or a complete nightmare that makes you want to abstract and refactor your classes. This question: [Detect target framework version at compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436526/detect-target-framework-version-at-compile-time) has an answer for handling different compile results depending on the target framework. Personally though, I like the modular route.

> I ask this because I don't know where I must declare my interface.
>   because my repository classes need to implement this interface, but
>   then this tie my dlls to my application, but I need to use this
>   repositories in two different applications, so I want to implement
>   once, and use in many applications. I want independent dlls, because
>   now are two applications, but in the future, can be more.
>
> The reason to want to use an interface in the application that uses
>   the repositories is because I would like to instantiate at runtime the
>   correct repository, according to the config file settings. So in the
>   fututre I can implement new repositories and there is no needed to
>   change the code.

Sounds like you need to create another library that is used to communicate between your UI and your Repository libraries. This can be a little tricky and overwhelming to set up just right. Basically you want your gateway DLL to house the interfaces and business objects. Your Application would reference this DLL and this DLL would reference your repositories.

Depending on your needs you may actually need to set up another intermediary DLL that would actually just house your interfaces and most basic utility classes. This would allow you to have your EF objects implement the same interface that your application is using without the need for your gateway DLL having to map your business objects and EF objects back and forth.

> EDIT1: I read about multi targeting, but if in my project I use
>   features for example of .NET 4.0 and I want to complie for 3.5, I get
>   an error because this feature does not exist in 3.5. That's correct.
>   Then the only way is to mantain two different projects? It would be a
>   double work.

I believe you can get around this by using the Preprocessor Directives I mentioned above. Below is just an example of making a method handle work differently depending on if the framework is .NET 2.0; it's just an example and not tested. The DefineConstants will need to be set up, but this should allow you to handle 1 project for multiple framework targets while also being able to use newer .NET features as they are released.

```
public Person FindPersonByName(List<Person> people, string name)
{
#if DOTNET_20
    foreach(Person person in people)
    {
        if (person.Name == name)
            return person;
    }
    return null;
#else
    return people.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == name);
#endif
}
```

I hope this was helpful and the best of luck in finding the right solution.