# Cannot using GetValues and SetValues in project C#

Tags: c#

I want to convert DataRow To Object. I write 1 class to do this.
Error like this:

`No overload for method 'SetValue' takes 2 arguments`

`No overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 arguments`

But I can't using GetValues() and SetValues(). When converting project to 4.5. It's work.
My project is set platform target is 3.5 (Obligatory - because I connect with the device must using .NET 3.5).

How to fix this?

Here my code:

```
    public DataRowToObject(DataRow row)
    {
        List<PropertyInfo> listProperty = this.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in listProperty)
        {
            if (!row.Table.Columns.Contains(prop.Name) ||
                row[prop.Name] == null ||
                row[prop.Name] == DBNull.Value)
            {
                prop.SetValue(this, null);
                continue;
            }

            try
            {
                object value = Convert.ChangeType(row[prop.Name], prop.PropertyType);
                prop.SetValue(this, value);
            }
            catch
            {
                prop.SetValue(this, null);
            }
        }
    }
    public virtual Hashtable GetParameters()
    {
        Type type = this.GetType();
        List<PropertyInfo> listProperty = new List<PropertyInfo>(type.GetProperties());

        Hashtable result = new Hashtable();
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in listProperty)
        {
            result.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(this));
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436526/detect-target-framework-version-at-compile-time

Comment: @Bharadwaj: How is that relevant?

Comment: @JonSkeet OP is using 4.5, but want to deploy for 3.5, was that link won't help in that way?

Comment: @Bharadwaj no, not at all. Have you actually read the question?

Comment: @Jcl hmm, might be I understood in wrong way, can you just explain what exactly OP wants? I commented as I understood

Comment: @Bharadwaj: Nope. There's no need to use conditional compilation here... there's not even any evidence that the OP needs to compile targeting two different frameworks, only 3.5.

Comment: @Bharadwaj his problem is that the overload he is using is only on .NET 4.5 and up, and was not in previous versions, so he's trying to find the equivalent for .NET 3.5... nothing to do with deploying for different versions

Comment: @JonSkeet then why did OP mentioned 4.5 if it is not relevant?

Comment: @Bharadwaj: Because it worked when they *did* target 4.5. Now they need to target 3.5 instead. Seems reasonable to me, but there's no indication that they need to target both at the same time.

Comment: @JonSkeet I still didn't got it. If OP changed to 3.5, then OP could have gone through the document for it

Comment: @Bharadwaj: But it wouldn't have helped them IMO. Whereas using an overload available in 3.5 (and 4.5) does.

Comment: @JonSkeet So the question confused for me. I didn't understood the what OP actually wants.

Comment: @Bharadwaj: The OP wants to call `PropertyInfo.GetValue` and `PropertyInfo.SetValue`. Their code worked when targeting .NET 4.5, but doesn't work when targeting .NET 3.5, because the overload they were using was only introduced in .NET 4.5. The solution is just to use a different overload.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an overload for `PropertyInfo.SetValue` and `PropertyInfo.GetValue` without the indexer added in .NET 4.5.

But it's simply a matter of passing `null` to the indexer parameter on previous versions (using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/xb5dd1f1(v=vs.90).aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/b05d59ty(v=vs.90).aspx) overloads).

So:

```
prop.SetValue(this, value, null);
```

And

```
prop.GetValue(this, null);
```

This should work on .NET .3.5 (up to recent versions)... actually for NET 2.0 and up :-)