# Is there a way to tell what version of the .Net Framework is being used by a #define

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have some .cs files that are shared amongst several projects and if possible I would like to be able to #define away things that are part of the 3.5 framework if I am attempting to compile to the 2.0 framework.  Is there a #define that is already built in to do this?

Comment: Not really, but this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408908/conditional-compilation-depending-on-the-framework-version-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to define constants based on $(TargetFrameworkVersion).

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436526/detect-target-framework-version-at-compile-time).