# Are there any default compilation symbols defined, like NET40 or NET20 or something?

Tags: c#

I'm curious if there's "default conditional compilation symbols" that are basically automatically defined by the C# compiler.  For instance, the compiler framework version, or anything.

I did a cursory check and did not see any defaults.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional compilation depending on the framework version in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/408908/conditional-compilation-depending-on-the-framework-version-in-c-sharp)

Comment: seems to be right... the answer was "There aren't any built in, but you can supply your own."

Answer (score 0):

In project build options You can enable DEBUG and TRACE constants (DEBUG is enabled/disabled based on Active Configuration by default). As far as I know, those are only default constants.

Answer (score 0):

From [this question that asked about a similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408908/conditional-compilation-depending-on-the-framework-version-in-c-sharp#408937) but asked the question in a different way

> There aren't any built in, but you can supply your own.