# C# preprocessor directive, version of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, preprocessor-directive

I need to make a preprocessor directive that will exclude a line of code only on ALL version of Visual Studio 2012.

Question 1: Is there a tag for all versions of VS2012? (I see people using `VS_2005_PRO` and similar, but I need all versions of 2012)

Question 2: is there a `#ifNOT` type command besides creating a logical `#elif`?

Comment: @Dai All of the answers in your linked duplicate checks the framework version the code is being compiled as, not the version of the compiler that is being used.

Comment: *"is there a #ifnot"* Yes, its in the format: `#if !TAG_NAME`, but I don't know of any defined directives for any version of Visual Studio, at least not in C#. Why do you have code that is specific to the IDE and not the framework?

Comment: See this answer from Mark Gravell: http://stackoverflow.com/a/408937/4798077

Comment: I have a suite of CodeWebTests, which the tag decoration causes errors on our build automator -- which is hardwired to VS2012, while the devs use 2013/2015.